# Label Smoothing in PyTorch - Using BCE loss -> doing it with the data itself

Tags: pytorch

i am doing a classification task (binary) in PyTorch, so with labels 0 und 1.
No I want introduce label smoothing as another regularization technique.
Because I Use the ice loss, there is no such function to use label smoothing as
in the cross entropy loss (for man than 0,1).
Now I am considering to implement it not in the loss but in the data itself.
Would it be right to just replace my y_true to for example 0->0.1 and 1->0.9
before they go into the loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation for label smoothing from  ["When Does Label Smoothing Help?"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02629) is:

```
y_ls = y(1 − α) + α/K
```

where α is the label smoothing parameter and K is the number of classes

so in python code:

```
eps = 0.1
y_true = y_true * (1 - eps) + (eps / 2)
```

or

```
y_true = y_true.clamp(eps / 2, (1 - eps) / 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the 0 with 0.1  and 1 with 0.9 if label smoothing is 0.1

```
criterion(disc_fake_pred, torch.zeros_like(disc_fake_pred)+0.1) #0.1
criterion(disc_real_pred, torch.ones_like(disc_real_pred)-0.1)  #0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Two simple alternatives:

```py
eps = 0.1
y_true = (1 - 2 * eps) * y_true + eps
```

Or use [`clamp`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.clamp.html):

```py
eps = 0.1
y_true = y_true.clamp(eps, 1 - eps)
```